# Bind data from a class and data from a list of classes to same WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, list, wpfdatagrid

I'm relatively new to WPF and I couldn't find anything solving my current issue so I'm trying here.
I have a class called ToolType which has a couple of parameters(name, id, model) and it also has a List of Tools(ID, RFID, shelfID).
In one of my views I need to show

```
    | ID | RFID | Name | Model | ShelfID |
```

as columns in a DataGrid, so a mixture of "parent" and "child" classes, but I just can't figure out how to go about doing that - besides making a completely new string array containing the information.
Does anyone have any idea how to it?

Code:

```
class Tool
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string RFID { get; set; }
    public string space { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

---

```
class ToolType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int interval { get; set; }
    public List<Tool> toolsList = new List<Tool>();
    ...
}
```

---

WPF for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="40,43,0,0" Name="dataGrid4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="305">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RFID}" Header="RFID" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Type" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding model}" Header="Model" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nextMaintenance}" Header="Dato" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding space}" Header="Plads" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: providing the code where you are trying to do this is always useful, so please do so.

Comment: What is your `DataContext` for the `DataGrid`?  How do you set it?

Comment: Set in the code as: 
dataGrid4.ItemsSource = Controller.Instance.toolTypes;
toolTypes being a List of ToolType class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about grouping your Tools by ToolType: [How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I'd still need to create a new List just to show the data - I was aiming towards using only the ToolType class and its Tool list. But I'll probably need to implement the sorting functions in the link

Comment: To put everything into one datagrid you need to create a new list, but you can use your ToolType as header for each list of tools (when grouping)...

Comment: So I -need- to create a new list containing the data from both classes? If it's the only way, then there's no point looking for different ways.